# Inserting multiple ObjectIds to sub-document at once with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, nosql

I'm using mongoose and I have the following model:

```
const UniversitySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Name is required']
    },
    color: {
        type: String
    },
    paths: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Path'
    }]
})
```

I want to be able to insert multiple paths (which cast to the Path model) into the universities collection when first creating it. I tried the following code:

```
const newUni = new University({
    name: name,
    paths: [...pathIds],
    color: color
})

newUni.save()
    .then(uni => {
            return res.send(uni)
        })
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
    })
```

However it raises this error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[ 5f122f9967c59932b44214b6, 5f2762858f9060327c4f6b2f ]" at path "_id" for model "Path"

 messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"[ 5f122f9967c59932b44214b6, 5f2762858f9060327c4f6b2f ]"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: [ 5f122f9967c59932b44214b6, 5f2762858f9060327c4f6b2f ],
  path: '_id',
  reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string 
of 24 hex characters
```

It looks like mongoose does not cast the Ids separately when there are more than one, because when I tried it with one id, it worked.

I also tried to save the documents and then push the ids to the path array, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to do it all at once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that there are no whitespaces in each of the array's `id`- values:

With this code

```
const newUni = new University({
    name,
    paths: ["5f122f9967c59932b44214b6","5f2762858f9060327c4f6b2f"],
    color
})
```

it should definitely work.

So assuming `pathIds` initially holds the string `" 5f122f9967c59932b44214b6, 5f2762858f9060327c4f6b2f "`, you can simply do

```
...
paths: pathIds.split(",").map(v => v.trim()),
...
```

to get an array of the trimmed `id`-values: